# Getting Error: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm working on face detection feature in my project. My code works perfectly on many devices including My device (Honor Play, Android 9.0)  but it's not working on some devices ex. Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 pro having same version (android 9.0) but i'm getting error as shown in logs below.

I have added following permissions in manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
```

I'm getting following error in logs

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
W/CamCtrl.V17: type=1400 audit(0.0:363016): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=13687 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c101,c260,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

I'm already requesting camera and storage permissions if required or not allowed.
Please let me know any solutions for this issue.

Comment: can you share code where you get this error ?

Comment: it is Kernel Issue SELinux Permissive Issue .You can try with changing package name of Redmi note 5 pro .for  your app .

Comment: I'm also facing the same error like you, my app uses background camera library and it works fine for couple of hours, im using it as a serivce through work manager class, but after some time, my device hangs and becomes unresponsive unless i reboot it, when i reboot i face the same problem, and i checked the logcat to find the same logs like you, so is there any fix for it?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue as @RohitBharadwaj faced, is there any solution??

Comment: @Abhra I just switched my entire app to use Camera2API and now the app is working.

Comment: ohhh, but in may case I just change the required field to true, and it worked for me. <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be a weird issue. I have been going through countless threads and I'm not able to figure out how to solve this? Does anyone have any working solution for this problem? Kind of feel like it's a bug in the Android code.

Comment: did you find any solution? I had the same problem like yours @imrankhan

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your phone OS, worked for me